# cron/php how to run command as a non root user

Tags: php, cron, root

I need to run command (only one command) as a non root user from cron.

Have tried two versions and both fails;

Cron:

```
* * * * * php script.php
```

script.php:

```
exec("whoami"); // returns 'root'
// version 1
exec("runuser -u www-data -- ls"); // error -> sh: 1: runuser: not found
// version 2
exec("su www-data -c 'ls'"); // error -> This account is currently not available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `root` crontab.
Use crontab for `www-data` user:

```
crontab -e -u www-data
```

or use a system crontab in `/etc/cron.d/` and specify user `www-data`.

```
* * * * * www-data php script.php
```

Comment: I need run as root. I need run only one command as non root, because it is execute program that not working under root. ls-command is just for example.

Comment: Your question states the following "I need to run command (only one command) as a non root user from cron".

Comment: Run the script as non-root and execute the commands that require root via sudo. Everything else is a potential security risk.

Comment: @holden321: You can have a crontab for each and every user on your machine and each crontab will operate independently of every other.  The purpose of cron is to start processes periodically.  There are no "dependencies" or "sequencing" between individual crontab entries - they are simply invoked when the timing criteria tell it to do so - the there is /no reason/ to start processes under other accounts.